# How do I resolve Wix form 'Couldn't submit due to temporary issue' error?

Tags: velo

I started making a couple of Wix sites.

A few weeks ago, the forms stopped working - I'd get an 'Couldn’t submit form due to a temporary issue' error. And they haven't worked since (same error).

I'm at a loss as to what's going on.

I've tried adding new forms, and alternate wix sites, without luck.

Is anyone else having this problem? It'd at least be reassuring to know it's not user-specific because I have few ideas about how to address the matter.

I should mention I'm using Velo, but I have no indication that it's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached out to Wix help for a solution.

They suggested that I needed to publish my site before submits would work - and stated that they'd succesfully tested a copy of my site.

While I had already published my site (and so it being published wasn't the issue), that confidence moved me to testing the form on the live version of the site (rather than in preview mode), which was successful.

Going forward I will just test the form on the live version of the site. I wonder if that's what I'd always been doing, in which case this post might hopefully at least help someone who similarly forgets.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to Wix support and they fixed it by having me go in my browser settings, clear my cache, close browser for 10 seconds, open wix editor, save and publish.